# Find rotor stator loss in a three-phase delta-connected induction motor

Tags: induction-motor, loss

I'm trying to work out stator input power of a three-phase delta-connected induction motor.

I have the equation Stator Input Power (P1), where P1 = Pm + rotor copper loss + rotor stator loss.

I have Pm and rotor copper loss but I don't know how to find the equation for rotor stator loss. If anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For an induction motor, the motor input power is equal to the mechanical power developed in the rotor plus the stator copper loss plus the rotor copper loss plus the iron loss.

The rotor copper loss is the mechanical power developed in the rotor multiplied by per-unit slip. Per-unit slip is (synchronous speed minus rotor speed) divided by synchronous speed.

Comment: I don't have iron loss given in my equation I have rotor copper loss and Pm. My equation is for Output power with friction losses. Where Pm= 2 x pi x nr and then did Pm-mechanical losses.

Comment: For rotor copper loss I first worked out Ir, then loss per phase and finally total copper loss.

Comment: How would I work out rotor stator loss?

Comment: I have never seen the term "rotor stator loss." The only losses in my books are the ones I listed plus mechanical losses and "stray losses." Stray losses are essentially losses that can not be determined.

Comment: How would you then work out input power then because I'm trying to work out input and output power so I can calculate the mechanical efficiency of my motor at full load running speed? would input power be mechanical power + mechanical losses. Mechanical losses was the only value I was given.

Comment: Mechanical power is my earlier equation Pm=2 x pi x nr isn't it? Then I'd just add mechanical losses. That would be for input power.

Comment: How would I calculate output power?

Comment: `How would I calculate output power?` As per your question, you `have Pm` - I take that to be the mechanical power, which is a motor's output.